# Not able to install python mysql module

Tags: python, mysql, django

i am trying to connect to mysql in django. it asked me to install the module. the module prerequisites are "MySQL 3.23.32 or higher" etc. do i really need to install mysql, cant i just connect to remote one??

Comment: Which box are you using?  Do you have access to remote one? If yes, then configure it

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the client libraries. The Python module is a wrapper around the client libraries. You don't need to install the server.